# To remove lines from a csv which have only commas

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed

I have a file which has some lines that have only commas, and no data. The issue is that the lines will not have fixed number of commas. The data may look like below-

```
99,abc,123,,
bcd,123,th
,,bcd,123,th
,,,,bcd,123,th
,,,
,,,,,
```

the output should look like

```
99,abc,123,,
bcd,123,th
,,bcd,123,th
,,,,bcd,123,th
```

I have to remove the lines which have only commas.

Comment: `grep -v '^,*$' file` or `sed '/^,*$/d' file`

Comment: Hi, these are not working. I can still see the lines which have only commas.

Comment: You probably have DOS line ending in your csv.  You can use `sed -E $'/^,+\\\r?$/d'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try single grep as follows.(negating those lines which have started from comma and till end they have comma, in all the commands same logic is used)

```
grep -v '^,*$'  Input_file
```

try with awk solution too as follows.

```
awk '!/^,*$/'  Input_file
```

try with sed solution too on same.

```
sed -n '/^,*$/d;p'  Input_file
```

Comment: Hi, these are not working. I can still see the lines which have only commas

Comment: Not sure, these all worked fine for me, could you please check if you have carriage characters in your Input_file by doing cat -v Input_file, if you see them you could remove them by doing tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file  Input_file   let me how it goes then.

Comment: Hi, it worked!! Thank you so much. My file had carriage characters.

Comment: Add `grep '[^,]'` to the list. That would also delete blank lines which may or may not be desirable.

Answer (score 2):

with **`awk`**

```
awk -F, '!/^,+$/{print}' file
```

or:

```
awk -F, '{p=1}/^,+$/{p=0}p' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This **grep** will remove all lines containing only commas (atleast one) and will keep the blank lines if you need. I believe your requirement is only to remove lines containing commas only.

```
grep -v "^,,*$" file
```

Input

```
99,abc,123,,
bcd,123,th
,,bcd,123,th
,,,,bcd,123,th


,,,
,,,,,
abc
```

Output:

```
99,abc,123,,
bcd,123,th
,,bcd,123,th
,,,,bcd,123,th


abc
```

If you want to remove blank lines also  then you can use :

```
grep -v "^,*$" file
```